# PHP - Change a variable's value for a later If statement within another variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I am trying to create a $clause variable that contains the variable $team1 and can change the value of the variable $team1 for a later If statement.

Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
$team1 = "";

$clause = "$team1 == 'Wildcats' OR $team1 == 'Bulldogs";

$team1 = 'Bears';

if ($clause) { echo "Yes"; }
else {echo "No";}
```

I would like $clause in the If statement to have the value (in this example):

```
'Bears' == 'Wildcats' OR 'Bears' == 'Bulldogs";
```

No matter what I make the value of $team1, the output is "Yes". How can I get the If statement to correctly determine if value of $team1 is (or isn't) meeting the condition in $clause?

Comment: Such approach usually should be avoided. What is the main task?

Comment: In the real code, I am pulling the values for the teams from a database. I am filling the $clause variable with these teams in a loop. I using $clause later to determine if the winner of a game is from a certain conference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback, I decided that I needed different approach to solve this problem. I was able to get what I wanted by putting the teams into an array ($teams) and then looping through that array with the If statement comparing to $team1. The following code works how I want it to by changing the value of $team1.

```
$teams = array('Wildcats', 'Bulldogs', 'Cougars');
$team1 = 'Bears';

$count = 0;
$met = "no";

do {
    if($team1 == $teams[$count]) { $met="yes"; break;}
    $count++;
} while ($count < count($teams));


echo $met;
```

Thanks to everyone for the help! I've used this forum a lot to solve previous problems, but this is the first time I've actually posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement checks whether or not the variable is declared or not. So it will always print "Yes".

The type you want can be acheived by using `eval` which translates text into PHP-Code.

See http://php.net/manual/de/function.eval.php for further instructions.

Answer (score 0):

use with some return function .Because variable already printed the value in first definition .so call function after if condition satisfied .Then new variable value was updated

```
    function varReset($team1){
    return "$team1 == 'Wildcats' OR $team1 == 'Bulldogs";
}
$team1 = "";
$clause = varReset($team1);
$team1 = 'Bears';
if ($clause) {
    $clause = varReset($team1);
    echo $clause;
    echo "Yes";
}
else {echo "No";}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is illogical because Php will execute statement line by line,
so 
$cause value will be (== 'Wildcats' OR  == 'Bulldogs') and 
then 
if($cause) -- will return TRUE because if will check the variable is 'isset' and 'not empty', It won't take as you expected condition
I recommend you to use function

```
function checkVal($param) {
    return ($param == 'Wildcats' || $param == 'Bulldogs') ?  "Yes" : "No";
}

echo checkVal('Bears');
```